# Python: Bitwise OR between integers

Tags: python, bit-manipulation, bitwise-or

I am seeing a strange behavior in python when performing bitwise operations

```
>>> bin(4)
'0b100'
>>> bin(9)
'0b1001'
>>> bin(9^4)
'0b1101'
```

Above I see the expected behavior for the OR, the numbers are aligned on the right and each bit is ORed  generating the result. However, when I OR two identical integers, the result is always 0 when it should be the number, in my opinion.

```
>>> bin(9^9)
'0b0'
```

Is this a bug or a very strange feature? Can anyone explain?

Comment: That's bitwise `xor` :-) By definition, `k^k` is 0. You're looking for `|`

Comment: http://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#binary-bitwise-operations

Comment: wow! what a stupid mistake! thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You are applying an exclusive or (`^`).
You're trying to apply a regular bitwise or (`|`).

From the [Python Wiki](http://wiki.python.org/moin/BitwiseOperators):

> ## x | y
>
> Does a "bitwise or".
>   Each bit of the output is 0 if the corresponding bit of x AND of y is 0, otherwise it's 1.
>
> ## x ^ y
>
> Does a "bitwise exclusive or".
>   Each bit of the output is the same as the corresponding bit in x if that bit in y is 0, and it's the complement of the bit in x if that bit in y is 1.

Answer (score 0):

^ is [Bitwise Exclusive Or](http://docs.python.org/2/library/operator.html)  ( AKA. XOR )

not **" OR "**

---

This is a truth table for Exclusive Or

[image: xor]

[source](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6HooM.gif)

So, you get 0 because XOR will output a 0 whenever the bits are identical/same.

In your case

`9^9`  or `9 XOR 9` will give you `0` because both are the same integers.